# Difference between Geth POA Clique and Parity POA Aura

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, proof-of-authority, clique, aura

I am creating my own private blockchain with a POA consensus. What is the difference between POA networks created by Geth (Clique) and by Parity (Aura), and are there scenarios that favor one over the other?

Answer (score 7):

Since some moderator decided to delete the only answer to this question here it is again:

I do not have time to summarize it.

> Good question!
>
> I don't have an answer but I do have a link that might be worth
>   reading
>
> In this paper we derive the functioning of two prominent consensus
>   algorithms for permissioned blockchains based on the PoA paradigm,
>   namely Aura and Clique.  We provide a qualitative comparison of them
>   with respect to PBFT in terms of consistency, availability and
>   performance, by considering a deployment over the Internet where the
>   network is realistically modelled as eventually synchronous rather
>   than synchronous. By  applying  the  CAP  Theorem,  we  claim  that 
>   in  this  setting  PoA  algorithms  can  give up  consistency  for 
>   availability  when  considering  the  presence  of  Byzantine  nodes. 
>   This  can prove  to  be  unacceptable  in  scenarios  where  the 
>   integrity  of  the  list  of  transactions  has  to be absolutely kept
>   (which is likely to be the actual reason why a blockchain-based
>   solution is used).  On the other hand,  PBFT keeps the blockchain
>   consistent at the cost of availability, even when the network behaves
>   temporarily asynchronously and Byzantine nodes are present; this
>   behaviours is much more desirable when data integrity is a priority. 
>   Despite one of the most praised advantages of PoA algorithms is their
>   performance, our qualitative analysis shows that in terms of latency
>   the expected loss of PBFT is bounded, and can be offset by the gain in
>   consistency guarantees. As  future  work,  we  plan  to  deepen  the 
>   analysis  of  PoA  algorithms  by  engaging  further reverse
>   engineering tasks and thorough experimental evaluations.  The final
>   goal is to validate and possible revise our claims on the availability
>   and consistency guarantees of PoA and PBFT, by implementing the
>   adverse scenarios we envisioned in Section 4.1.  Furthermore, we want
>   to collect real performance measurements, both transaction latency and
>   throughput, and to test scalability  with  respect  to  varying  input
>   transaction  rates  and  number  of  nodes/authorities. Moreover,  we
>   are moving towards a formalisation of permissioned blockchains so to
>   define a framework for benchmarking and evaluating these algorithms
>   with a more formal approach.
>
> http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2058/paper-06.pdf

Comment: The paper is good. It gives good insights into how Aura, Clique and PBFT work and what their strengths/limitations from the CAP perspective are.

Comment: I know but it got removed because I didn't summarize it. I didn't read it (skimmed it halfway) so I can't summarize it but it's still a good reference. Moderator doesn't seem to get basic things, probably butthurt over something.

Comment: Hi there. The problem with posting links without a summary is that the link can either be moved or become dead at any time, as has happened with numerous past answers. The moderators work according to a set of rules which generally work, and disallowing link-only answers is one of them. Here's the main site-wide Meta Stack Exchange discussion on the topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Which is also why I explicitly stated that I do not have an answer. 
One reference and 0 answers is better than no references and no answers. 
If someone feels like summarizing the link, go ahead and I'll gladly delete my answer.

Comment: Totally better a link that works but _may_ disappear than no info at all. The mod must have Google stock and pretend to follow some general rules while forcing the community to start looking from scratch.